# Problem to Load PHP File In different Divs After Page Load and refresh them Using JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am having a problem to show different types of graphs in different divs using Javascript and JQuery in a HTML file.

I am using a single PHP file that generates those graphs according to the parameters I pass it through the URL (GET Method). The PHP files imports the data from a PostgreSQL database and creates the graphs using FLOT Library. 
After loading the page I want to show the graphs, and after 1 minute, I want to refresh each graph, I am using JQuery to achieve this.

If I use only one div showing only one graph it works just fine, it show the graph and refreshes it.

The problem is when I try to load different graphs in different divs because it only shows the initial graph in the first div only, and then it goes refreshing and showing the other graphs but in the same div # 1.

Can someone give an idea how to solve it? or tell me what is wrong in the code?

This is the code I'm using:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function update()
        {
            $('#flot1').load('basic.php?p=1&c1=00b8d8&c2=eff9fb');
            $('#flot2').load('basic.php?p=2&c1=8be3b8&c2=f1fbf6');
        }
        setInterval( "update()", 60000 );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "flot1"></div>
        <div id = "flot2"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){     
         $("#flot1").load('basic.php?p=1&c1=00b8d8&c2=eff9fb');    
         $("#flot2").load('basic.php?p=2&c1=8be3b8&c2=f1fbf6');

         });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the code of the PHP file that creates the graphs:

```
<html>
 <head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="flot/jquery.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
    <div id="placeholder" style="width:202px;height:140px;"></div>
    <?php
    include "opendb.php";
    if(!isset($tag)){ $tag=$_GET['p']; }
    if(!isset($c1)) { $c1="#".$_GET['c1']; }
    if(!isset($c2)) { $c2="#".$_GET['c2']; }

    $dataset1 = array();
    $query1="SELECT nu_valor, nu_fecha_hora_timestamp FROM x001t_historico_tag WHERE co_tag = '$tag' ORDER BY nu_fecha_hora_timestamp DESC LIMIT 6";
    $result1 = pg_query($query1);
    while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result1)) 
    {
        $unix      = $row['nu_fecha_hora_timestamp'];
        $nu_valor   = $row['nu_valor']; 
        $dataset1[] = array( $unix, $nu_valor );
    }

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var dataset1 = <?php echo json_encode($dataset1); ?>;
    $(function () {
    var options = {  xaxis: { ticks: [] }, yaxis: { ticks: [], autoscaleMargin: 0.5 }, grid: { backgroundColor: '#fff', color: "#fff" },
                  };
    //plotting
    $.plot($("#placeholder"),[
        {
            color: '<?php echo $c1; ?>',  data: dataset1 , 
            lines: { show: true, fill: true, fillColor: "<?php echo $c2; ?>", lineWidth: 2},

        } ], options);
    });
    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

If I run the graph from the browser passing it the parameters through the URL it also works fine and creates the graph.

Comment: Could you add the results from `basic.php` to the question please

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I see code repetition. Why not use `update()` in your second script, instead of writing out the code twice?

Comment: The script in the <head> section is used to refresh the graphs after 1 minute. The second script is used to load the graphs inmediately after the page is fully loaded.

Comment: Check if there some error outputed in console of the browser.